# how to take specific data from a log file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am beginner to python and I have a log file which contains MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED where I already took the information of username, timestamp and IP address.

My question is how can I take a username who has changed password for 10 times from log file, because the condition is whenever a user changes password for 10 times, we need the detail of the user such as username, timestamp and IP address. 
This is my log file:

```
20170119 193739188+0900 elim1td001p imapserv 52324 75559 132341478487808 Note;UserDataException(504/1) MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED:{protocolType=[imap], userName=[teasst_emailrei_6000], password=[XXXXX]}:AuthenticateAndGetMailboxService\3aPOST:Authenticating Failed.::user=test_emaili_3000:cmd=1 LOGIN teasst_emailrei_6000 <password>:fromhost=129.0.0.1:sid=b34f10a-fd04-11e7-b246-7f629ba04def
```

This is my python code

```
import re
from csv import writer
import datetime
log_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/ip.txt'
output_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/output.csv'

name_to_check = 'MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'

with open(log_file,encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if name_to_check in line:
            username = re.search(r'(?<=userName=\[)(.*)(?=\],)', line)
            username = username.group()

            date = re.search(r'(?P<date>\d{8})\s+(?P<time>\d{9})\+(?P<zone>\d{4})', line)
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.group('date'), "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            print(date)

            time = re.search(r'(?P<date>\d{8})\s+(?P<time>\d{9})\+(?P<zone>\d{4})', line)
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.group('time'), "%H%M%S%f").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print(time)

            ip = re.search(r'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])',line)
            ip = ip.group()

            with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
                csv_writer = writer(outfile)
                csv_writer.writerow(["Username","Date","Time","Ip"])
                csv_writer.writerow([username,date,time,ip])
```

Comment: What about this doesn't work? In order for us to help you better we need you to tell us what's wrong with the code you have.

Comment: @RThomP  I want to know that how can I take a username who has changed the password for 10 times from the string MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. We need to take from here since there are many log files with the capacity of 20tb

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do with your code, but why isn't the code you've written working?

Comment: Are you able find the username of a user that changed it once with the message `MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` using the current code?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub yes the code is working and it shows all username, but it does not show the specific username who has changed the password for 10 times and I need to know how to take it

Answer (score 1):

you can append the username into a list then use collection.counter to get the count:

```
from collections import Counter
usernamelist = []
usernamelist.append('tom')
usernamelist.append('tom')
usernamelist.append('tom')
usernamelist.append('sam')
usernamelist.append('louis')
c = Counter(usernamelist)
list_of_user_more_than_one = [i for i in c if c[i] > 1]
print(list_of_user_more_than_one)
--->['tom']
```

Comment: But i have lots of users in that 20tb, how can I write it one by one

Comment: You add usernamelist.append(username) in your for loop

Comment: This is the kind of solution you want to use @KatarinaAlves. Of course you'll not write all the usernames by hand. But each time your loop will match a user, add it to the list

Comment: @LouisNg I have tried the code you gave, but this shows the result of whole users detail, not the user who has changed password for 10 times. The point is that whenever a user makes a wrong password for many times

Comment: ex: If the user type wrong password for 2 times, he is still the user. If the stranger type wrong password for 10 times, then he is the anonymous user, not the real user.